How to add timeout to REST API call on aws amplify v6?
I'm currently upgrading from v5 to v6 of amplify and there are breaking changes. One is the API call. I can't find a way to add timeout on post method. The cypress tests fails because we are expecting a certain timeout time which is 2mins.
This is the v5
post(apiName, path, options: {headers, body, timeout});

This is v6
post({apiName, path, options: {headers, body}});

Adding timeout on options doesn't work so I'm not sure where to put it now after the upgrade.
The timeout for Cypress tests is up to 5 seconds only so we can test the timeout response faster but the new API doesn't accept or reads the timeout property. I didn't remove it from the options in the API call but it seems not working.

Looks like the option is indeed not there yet, judging by the issue being tagged as feature-request (did you start the issue btw?): https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/13426

Thanks for the comments. Yeah, the aws-amplify team did not add the option timeout on their API call as per commented on the github issue you mentioned.
